# Custom mapping with Automapper where a field in destination is the concatenation of two fields in source

Tags: c#, converters, automapper

I think that the title already quite explains the problem. I have a source type:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string srcImage { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use automapper to convert from EmployeeViewModel to Employee and the **name** of Employee is the concatenation of **name**  and **surname** in EmployeeViewModel.

May you kindly explain me how to set the MapperConfiguration? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeViewModel, Employee>()
                        .ForMember(d => d.Name, d => d.MapFrom(x => string.Format("{0}{1}", x.Name, x.Surname)));
```